# oracle REGEXP .* understanding concern

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, sql-like, regexp-like

Question- select all city from station table where start and end letter of city must be any vowel (a/e/i/o/u).

The solution which I through:
`` SELECT city FROM station WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (city, '^(a|e|i|o|u)$', 'i')```

But this is not Giving any output, I searched for the solution online and here is the working code:
`` SELECT city FROM station WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (city, '^(a|e|i|o|u).*(a|e|i|o|u)$', 'i')```

I tried to search online but didn't understood why applying **.*** in between worked.  For my code I think its not working as I am using same sub expression for start(^) and end($).

Can anyone please help me understand the **.*** working here.

Comment: `'^(a|e|i|o|u).*(a|e|i|o|u)$'` will only match values which are longer than one character. If someone names a city "A" then you will not match it with that regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

- `.` means *any character*
- `*` means *zero or more occurrences* of that "any character"

More info in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm).

So, it looks for strings that start `^` with a vowel, followed by no other characters (or maybe followed by many other characters), and ends  with a vowel again.

Answer (score 0):

The `.` represents any character, and the following `*` says you accept any number of occurrences of it, including zero occurrences. So the combination works like the single `*` in MS DOS or like `%` in a SQL `LIKE` pattern.

```
'^(a|e|i|o|u)$'
```

wants the beginning of a string, one vowel, then the end of the string. So 'a' matches, but 'aa' and 'aba' don't.

```
'^(a|e|i|o|u).*(a|e|i|o|u)$'
```

wants the beginning of a string, one vowel, optionally any characters, then a vowel, then the end of the string. So 'a' matches, and so do 'aa' (vowel, zero characters, vowel), and 'aba' (vowel, one character, vowel), and 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstu' (vowel, several characters, vowel).